# how hide google chart's first gridline

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i need to hide the first gridline of a chart

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fESWS.png) is an example

this are the options that i'm using now

```
var options = {
              colors:['#A6A6A6'],
              width: 450,
              height: 250,
              legend: {
                  position: "none"
              },
              chartArea:{left:30,top:20,width:400,height:200},
              vAxis: {
                  gridlines: {color: 'none'},
              },
              hAxis: {
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {color: 'none'},
              },
              bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
          };
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According to Google Chart documentation, the first line that you are trying to remove is the baseline. Just add this property to your options no line will be displayed. Remember to add like :  `baselineColor: 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

using the options you've provided, the first gridline does not appear...?

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Category', 'value'],
    ['a', 2924],
    ['b', 2075],
    ['c', 2516],
    ['d', 2153],
    ['e', 2348],
    ['f', 1925]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  var options = {
    colors:['#A6A6A6'],
    width: 450,
    height: 250,
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
    chartArea:{left:30,top:20,width:400,height:200},
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {color: 'none'},
    },
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none',
      gridlines: {color: 'none'},
    },
    bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: could you please share the rest of the code? seems to work fine here...

Comment: it's the opposite, currently the line appears and I want the to hide it @WhiteHat

Comment: when I run the above snippet, I don't see a line

Comment: Finally I solved it puttin the first tick over 0, that hide the 0 line.

Answer (score 0):

@WhiteHat I'm still getting the black line, this is my code:

```
function init() {
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages:["corechart"], callback: 'drawCharts' });
}

function drawCharts() {
                drawChart1('chart1');
            }

function drawChart1(containerId) {
  var options = {
      colors:['#002060'],
      width: 450,
      height: 200,
      legend: {
          position: "none"
      },
      chartArea:{left:40,top:20,width:350,height:200},
      vAxis: {
          gridlines: {color: 'none'},
          textStyle: {
              fontSize: 9,
          }
      },
      hAxis: {
          textPosition: 'none',
          gridlines: {color: 'none'},
      },
      annotations: {
        stem: {
          color: 'none'
        },
        alwaysOutside : true,
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 9,
          color: '#000',
          auraColor: 'none'
        },
        style: 'point',
      },
      bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
  };
  var dataArray = [];
  dataArray.push(["Mix", "Useful surface (m²)", { role: 'annotation' }]);
  dataSurface.forEach(function(item, index){
    dataArray.push([item["mix"], parseFloat(item["useful_surface"]), parseFloat(item["useful_surface"])]);
  });
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '#.00'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 2);
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(containerId));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<body onload="init()">
   <div id="chart1"></div>
</body>
```